# c# - reading/writing blob from firebird

Tags: c#, blob, firebird

I'm trying to read image from firebird with c#, and save it to file system.
I can read from table and save. but image can not be viewed. I tried many piece of
code on net.but result is same :(
Can any one help me please?

Answer (score 2):

How are you retrieving the code form Firebird? If you are getting the data and casting it to a byte[] try:

```
byte [] blob = row["image"];
// create a file FileStream to write the data
FileStream fs = new FileStream("image.jpg", FileMode.Create); 
fs.Write(blob,0,blob.Length);
fs.Close();
```

The above code should do the trick.

PS: I have made  lots of assumption in the code, but you can get the idea.