# Is it possible to write large strings to Firebird blob?

Tags: c#, blob, firebird

The documentation for Firebird implies that you can write large (> 60K) strings to a blob value in a table.  So if you have this:

```
CREATE TABLE MyBlobTable (
theId int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
theBlob BLOB SUB_TYPE 1
)
```

Then this should work:

```
insert into MyBlobTable (theId, theBlob) values (1, '[60K characters in a string]')
```

(example inspired by http://web.firebirdsql.org/dotnetfirebird/blob-sub_type-1-reading-example-csharp.html)

But I've found that neither C# drivers nor FlameRobin can write this value.  You get 'Unexpected end of command' (pointing to a spot about 32K into the string, which is a little suspicious)

I figure there is a special way to quote or escape the data values, or maybe a C# equivalent of this Java code (http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq372/) where a binary file is read directly into the statement.  I'm not doing anything fancy with the text data so I'm open to storing it as a binary blob if needed.

Thanks!

Update: "parameterized queries" is the phrase that I was looking for.  What I'm doing:

```
FbParameter param = new FbParameter("@blobVal", FbDbType.Text);
param.Value = myLargeString;
String query = "insert into MyBlobTable (theId, theBlob) values (1, @blobVal)";
using (FbConnection conn = [something from my pool]) {
    using (FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand(query, conn)) {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you remind us what SUBTYPE 1 is? Anyway, try using a parameter.

Comment: BLOB SUB_TYPE 1 maps to strings in C#, whereas BLOB maps to byte array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding text inline in the query. Then there are limits: first query text in Firebird 2.5 and earlier is limited to 64 KB, in Firebird 3.0 this was increased to 10 MB, but some tools may still use the API in a way that limits it to 64KB. There is also a limit to the string literal size: 32KB, or since Firebird 3.0 64KB if it is a literal for a blob value.

If you want to add more data to a blob, you need to stream it to the blob using parametrized queries. See [this example](https://web.archive.org/web/20191024114358/http://firebirdsql.org:80/en/net-examples-of-use/#update_text_blob_field):

> ```
> public static void Main(string[] args) {
>     // Set the ServerType to 1 for connect to the embedded server
>     string connectionString =
>         "User=SYSDBA;" +
>         "Password=masterkey;" +
>         "Database=SampleDatabase.fdb;" +
>         "DataSource=localhost;" +
>         "Port=3050;" +
>         "Dialect=3;" +
>         "Charset=NONE;" +
>         "Role=;" +
>         "Connection lifetime=15;" +
>         "Pooling=true;" +
>         "Packet Size=8192;" +
>         "ServerType=0";
>     
>     FbConnection myConnection = new FbConnection(connectionString);
>     myConnection.Open();
>     
>     FbTransaction myTransaction = myConnection.BeginTransaction();
>     
>     FbCommand myCommand = new FbCommand();
>     
>     myCommand.CommandText =
>         "UPDATE TEST_TABLE_01 SET CLOB_FIELD = @CLOB_FIELD WHERE INT_FIELD = @INT_FIELD";
>     myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
>     myCommand.Transaction = myTransaction;
>     
>     myCommand.Parameters.Add("@INT_FIELD", FbType.Integer, "INT_FIELD");
>     myCommand.Parameters.Add("@CLOB_FIELD", FbType.Text, "CLOB_FIELD");
>     
>     myCommand.Parameters[0].Value = 1;
>     myCommand.Parameters[1].Value = GetFileContents(@"GDS.CS");
>     
>     // Execute Update
>     myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
>     
>     // Commit changes
>     myTransaction.Commit();
>     
>     // Free command resources in Firebird Server
>     myCommand.Dispose();
>     
>     // Close connection
>     myConnection.Close(); 
> }
>
> public static string GetFileContents(string fileName) {
>     StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open));
>     string contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
>     reader.Close();
>     return contents; 
> }
> ```

Comment: Unfortunately this example can't be found anymore, can you please check?

Comment: @anli I couldn't find a replacement, so I linked to the Wayback Machine, and quoted the example from there

Answer (score 1):

I think that you're hitting the [max length of `varchar(n)` type](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-technical-specifications/) limit - 32767 bytes. Althougth the destination field is BLOB, the API will treat the value as varchar as you're providing it as a string literal. So the solution should be to use parametrized query (sorry, I don't use C# myself and thus can't provide example).

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this large string is to much for the SQL statement. I also read [here](http://www.volny.cz/iprenosil/interbase/ip_ib_strings.htm) that blobs within Firebird are not accessible through SQL for writing (but i'm not sure whether this information is correct).

Anyway, you can use streams for writing / reading blobs. For example, from SO: [c# - reading/writing blob from firebird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590508/c-sharp-reading-writing-blob-from-firebird), using a byte array for storage, but it should also work with strings.

Comment: I've read both of those links - the first one gave me hope that actually writing a long string to a blob would be possible.  The part about not using SQL is for pre-0.9.4 so I'm good.  The answer in the second link is really about how to write binary data to a file - which at this point is a problem that I'd like to have :)

Comment: Ok, so did you actually try using streams?

Comment: I'm not sure where using streams to write to a Firebird database in C# is documented - can you provide links?

Comment: All the links i've found are for IBProvider. But you are using DotNetFirebird. Unfortunately i cannot find anything about streams. So how they actually **write** a blob with an image?