# How to add binary data and string data to firebird database simultaneously in c#

Tags: c#, firebird, firebird-embedded

I am currently using this code to attempt saving binary data (pdf file) and string data at the same time:

```
string qy = 
String.Format( @"INSERT INTO publications (  uploader ,  filename ,  title ,  authors ,  keywords ,  file_data ,  insertdate  )                    
VALUES
( '{0}' , '{1}' , '{2}' , '{3}' , '{4}' , @file_data , '{5}' ) ",
 staffid, filemd5, title, author, keyword, DateTime.Now );


using( FbConnection fconn = connect_to_fbserver() ) 
{   
    FbCommand fbcom = new FbCommand( qy, fconn );   
    FbParameter parBlob = new FbParameter( "file_data", FbDbType.Binary );      
    parBlob.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;  parBlob.Value = filearray;  
    fbcom.Parameters.Add( parBlob );  

    fbcom.Connection.Open();
    fbcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

This code above fails because the binary data is blank (although the other string data were inserted appropriately).

I can't believe I spent the whole day tweaking this (thanks to the poorly documented firebird ibphoenix pages)

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8558664/898142

Comment: You really shouldn't use `String.Format()` to add values into a query string, it leaves you open to SQL injection, use parameters for all values.

Comment: Note that specifying `parBlob.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output` is wrong. The parameter direction is only relevant for calling stored procedures, and signifies output from the stored procedure to the caller (the client). The role of the parameter here is input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the following solution (thanks to comment by alexm):

```
string insert_query = @"INSERT INTO publications
( 
UPLOADER , 
FILENAME , 
TITLE , 
AUTHORS , 
KEYWORDS , 
FILE_DATA , 
INSERTDATE  ) 

VALUES
( '{0}' , '{1}' , '{2}' , '{3}' , '{4}' , @FILE_DATA , '{5}' ) ",
staffid, filemd5, title, author, keyword, DateTime.Now );

using( FbConnection myConnection = utility.connect_to_fbserver() )
{
    myConnection.Open();
    FbTransaction myTransaction = myConnection.BeginTransaction();

    FbCommand myCommand = new FbCommand();
    myCommand.CommandText = insert_query;

    myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
    myCommand.Transaction = myTransaction;

    myCommand.Parameters.Add( "@FILE_DATA", FbDbType.Binary, filearray.Length, "FILE_DATA" );

    myCommand.Parameters[0].Value = filearray;

    // Execute query
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // Commit changes
    myTransaction.Commit();

    // Free command resources in Firebird Server
    myCommand.Dispose();
}
```

However, I should mention that following the comment by Mark Rottevell, the following firebird query construction gives `Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -303 internal error`

```
string insert_query = @"INSERT INTO publications
( 
UPLOADER , 
FILENAME , 
TITLE , 
AUTHORS , 
KEYWORDS , 
FILE_DATA , 
INSERTDATE  ) 

VALUES

( @UPLOADER , @FILENAME, @TITLE , @AUTHORS, @KEYWORDS, @FILE_DATA , @INSERTDATE) ";

using( FbConnection myConnection = utility.connect_to_fbserver() )
{
    myConnection.Open();
    FbTransaction myTransaction = myConnection.BeginTransaction();

    FbCommand myCommand = new FbCommand();
    myCommand.CommandText = insert_query;

    myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
    myCommand.Transaction = myTransaction;

    myCommand.Parameters.Add( "@UPLOADER", FbDbType.Text, staffid.Length, "UPLOADER" );
    myCommand.Parameters.Add( "@FILENAME", FbDbType.Text, filemd5.Length, "FILENAME" );
    myCommand.Parameters.Add( "@TITLE", FbDbType.Text, title.Length, "TITLE" );
    myCommand.Parameters.Add( "@AUTHORS", FbDbType.Text, author.Length, "AUTHORS" );
    myCommand.Parameters.Add( "@KEYWORDS", FbDbType.Text, keyword.Length, "KEYWORDS" );
    myCommand.Parameters.Add( "@FILE_DATA", FbDbType.Binary, filearray.Length, "FILE_DATA" );
    myCommand.Parameters.Add( "@INSERTDATE", FbDbType.Text, today.Length, "INSERTDATE" );

    myCommand.Parameters[0].Value = staffid;
    myCommand.Parameters[1].Value = filemd5;
    myCommand.Parameters[2].Value = title;
    myCommand.Parameters[3].Value = author;
    myCommand.Parameters[4].Value = keyword;
    myCommand.Parameters[5].Value = filearray;
    myCommand.Parameters[6].Value = today;
        // Execute query
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // Commit changes
    myTransaction.Commit();

    // Free command resources in Firebird Server
    myCommand.Dispose();
}
```